# ¿Cómo descarto cambios no indexados en Git?

Tags: git, control-de-versiones

¿Cuál es la mejor manera de descartar los cambios de mi copia de local de trabajo que no están indexados aún?

- `git stash save --keep-index`
- `git checkout -- .`
- `git-clean`
- `git diff | git apply --reverse`
- `git clean -df`

Comment: Te referís a que no están commiteados?

Comment: @Carlos Laspina ya probaste con git clean -f

Comment: @Kleith si, así mismo. Cambios no comiteados.

Comment: @RaulCacacho si te fijas, esta en mi listado solo que con el -d incluido (que incluye borrar directorios nuevos). La pregunta más bien va para entender cual opción elegir como buena práctica.

Comment: Probá con `git reset --hard`, que elimina todo cambio no commiteado.

Comment: Ojo! que el **git reset --hard** también vuelva atrás aquellos cambios que si están indexados y tuvieron modificaciones. Además la consulta va mas para la parte de cual sería la mejor práctica

Comment: `git-clean` es un comando particular? o debiera ser `git clean`?

Answer (score 0):

Debería ser una combinación de `git checkout -- .` y `git clean -df`

`git checkout -- .` y `git diff | git apply --reverse` no tienen en cuenta los archivos que no están trackeados.

`git stash`  sirve pero se guardan copias de los objetos.

`git clean -df` descarta todos los archivos y directorios que no están bajo control de versiones. Pero **no descarta** las modificaciones de los archivos que si estan bajo control.

Hay que combinar ambos:

```
git checkout -- .
git clean -df
```

Answer (score 0):

Si por indexados, de verdad quisiste decir, en el *index*, osea, en el *staging area*, puedes probar primero con:

```bash
$ git clean -n  # Y vemos que archivos se irán a borrar
would remove archivo_no_en_el_index1
would remove archivo_no_en_el_index2
would remove archivo_no_en_el_index3
$ git clean -f  # Si nos gusta lo que vemos, entonces le ponemos el parámetro -f
```

Si quieres salvar los archivos que tienes en tu workdir, primero has un:

```
$ git stash push -m "nombre de estos cambios"
```

Esto aplica con archivos que ya están trackeados; si aún no lo están, añadelos con `git add <archivos a trackear>`, y ahora si repite el comando de arriba.

Y se guardarán en una cola a la que podrás acceder con:

- `git stash list`, para ver la cola y sus índices
- `git stash apply "stash@{<numero de stash>}"`, para aplicar los cambios que habías guardado en el stash
- `git stash clean`, para no ser cochino y tener un stash limpio luego de los cambios aplicados